# jQuery UI sortable: get first item before and after drag

Tags: jquery-ui, events, jquery-ui-sortable

My web app has a feature where users can create a list of up to five items. When a list is created, we automatically name it after the first item, though the user can also type a custom name. So, you'll have something like this:

```
Name: [ Item 1 ] (this is a text box)

- Item 1
- Item 2
- Item 3
- Item 4
- Item 5
```

I've also set up jQuery UI's `sortable` interaction so that users can click and drag to rearrange items in the list. Now, what I want to do is auto-rename the list after whatever the first item is once the user completes a drag, but *only if* they haven't entered a custom name (which can be determined by comparing the name to the original first item and seeing if they match).

I know that `sortable` provides a number of events that you can use to run custom functions (like `start` and `stop`). The problem is that I need to run functions both before and after the drag happens in order to do the comparison, but (as far as I know) I can't pass data between them - a variable defined in `start` can't be used in `stop`. So how would I write this?

Comment: I think it's more a matter of believes, would you tolerate a more global variable (outside the event function) in an answer? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by saving the first item in a global variable on `start`, then using that to compare to the current title on `stop`. Maybe not the best way to do it, but it does work:

```
var saveFirstItem = function(first_item) {
    startFirstItem = first_item;
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#list").sortable({
        start: function(event, ui){
            var first_item = $("#list li:first-child").text();
            saveFirstItem(first_item);
        },
        stop: function(event, ui){      
            var first_item = $("#list li:first-child").text();      
            var current_title = $("#title").val();

            if (current_title == startFirstItem){
                $("#title").val(first_item);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the most academic answer but here is an idea :

Why would you need the start event? If I understood correctly, all you seem to care about is to put the first item of the list in the field, but only if the name is not handwritten.
You might need a start event if you make this droppable, to add the first ever item dropped the name of the list, but I guess you have that already?

```
var nameIsCustom=false;
$("#ul").sortable(
{
    stop: function(event,ui)
    {
        nameIsCustom = true;
        $("ul > li").each(function()
        {
            if($("#name").val() == $(this).text())
            {nameIsCustom = false;}
        });
        if(!nameIsCustom)
        {
            $("#name").val($("#ul > li:first").text());
        }
    }
});
```